# Ignore inner object if all the properties are null during ObjectMapper deserialization

Tags: java-8, json-deserialization, objectmapper

I have a below Product class

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Product {
    private String id;
    private String status;
    private Price price
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Price {
    private String originalPrice;
    private String newPrice;
}
```

After deserialization I'm getting the output json as below

```
{
  "id" : 2113,
  "status" : "New",
  "price" : { },
}
```

But I'm expecting the output as below without price details as price has all the attributes as null

```
{
  "id" : 2113,
  "status" : "New"
}
```

I tried @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) at class level but its not working.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY` does not work for arbitrary classes in the same way as it does for arrays, collections and strings. Those have `isEmpty` method, so the object mapper can check whether those fields are empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because your Price object is not null. Somewhere Price is initialized and included empty.

See example [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-include-non-empty.html)

If this is not the case then, you can add code for your service/controller which returns Product.